# How to link inputs to new questions in Python (troubleshooting program)?

Tags: python

I was programming a troubleshooter on python and I have been finding it really hard to link inputs to new questions:

```
   Question 1
   print("Has your car got a flat tyre? 1. Yes 2. No")
   choice=input("1/2")
   if choice == "1":
        goto (Question 2) #How do I link this input
   elif choice == "2":
        goto (Question 3)
   else:
        print("Answer not applicable")
   Question 2                 #Into this question?
   print("Have you taken your car to the petrol station? 1. Yes 2. No")
   choice=input("1/2")
   if choice == "1":
       goto (Question 4)
   elif choice == "2":
       goto (Question 5)
   else:
       print("Answer not applicable")
   Question 3
   print("Has your car recently had an MOT? 1. Yes 2. No")
   choice=input("1/2")
   if choice == "1":
       goto (Question 6)
   elif choice == "2":
       goto (Question 7)
   else:
       print("Answer not applicable")
```

I need to know how to do this before I go further with my project. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that, it doesn't make sense. Python doesn't have GOTOs, you can't just jump to some marker. Consider using functions to represent questions, then calling the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support labels and goto. What you should be doing is something like the code below.

```
QUESTION_1 = "Has your car got a flat tyre? 1. Yes 2. No"
QUESTION_2 = "Have you taken your car to the petrol station? 1. Yes 2. No"
QUESTION_3 = "Has your car recently had an MOT? 1. Yes 2. No"
QUESTION_4 = "" 
QUESTION_5 = "" 
QUESTION_6 = ""
QUESTION_7 = "" 

def ask_question(question):
    print(question)
    answer = input()
    return answer

def check_answer(question, answer):
    if question == QUESTION_1 and answer == "1":
        question = QUESTION_2
    elif question == QUESTION_1 and answer == "2":
        question = QUESTION_3
    elif question == QUESTION_2 and answer == "1":
        question = QUESTION_4
    elif question == QUESTION_2 and answer == "2":
        question = QUESTION_5
    elif question == QUESTION_3 and answer == "1":
        question = QUESTION_6
    elif question == QUESTION_3 and answer == "2":
        question = QUESTION_7
    else:
        print("Answer not applicable")

    return question

question = QUESTION_1

while True:
    answer = ask_question(question)
    question = check_answer(question)
```

Comment: That's an inelegant way to do things - why not a list or dictionary of questions?

Comment: I agree that's unelegant, but the user clearly does not have much knowledge in Python, so I've implemented a solution without data structures since he probably has no experience with those.